# Change Visual Studio Scrollbar Caret Color in Map Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2017

The Scroll Bar Map Mode has an issue with the caret position color in dark mode:
[image]

It is showing as very bright gray line, which overpowers some of the other colors like the purple matching color I have.  I have been unable to find the caret color for the scroll bar in the Environment > Font and Colors dialog (The default caret color doesn't affect it).  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment > Fonts and colors > Display items: "Overview caret", Item foreground: *choose color*

Comment: Curious how you found this 8 month old question to answer... But I appreciate the answer regardless.

Comment: After searching myself and not finding the answer, I dug around the options and decided to share the knowledge for those in the future :)